# java cannot assign a string contains plus symbol

Tags: java

[image: I want assign a string value,this is dubug module, but where is the plus sign?]

as you can see,I want assign a string value to this.where,this is dubug module, but where is the plus sign?

Comment: where is a local variable, not an instance variable, so can not be called with this. please, for future reference: no screenshots of code, just the code itself will do

Comment: @Stultuske sorry for only post a picture, but the picture contains all I want expression，and thank you RustyX Solved my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is a special character in a URL. It's an encoded version of a space.

If you need to send an actual `+` you need to encode it as `%2B`.